# Paperclip not create thumbnail if original file is too small

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I use paperclip and setup following.

```
has_attached_file :attached,
      :styles => {
        :small => ["170x170>", :jpg], :large => ["400x400>", :jpg]
      }
```

I want that thumbnail is not created if original file is too small.
Example, if original file is 250x250, "small thumbnail" is created(170x170),
but, large thumbnail is not created.

But, above setting, both "small" and "large" is created...

Additionally, I want to switch thumbnail setting.
Example, 
case1 : if original file is 250x250, both "small" and "large" thumbnail is created.
case2 : if original file is 250x250, only "small" thumbnail is created.

I want to dynamically swith case1 and case2.

Do you have any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question: 
Paperclip not create thumbnail if original file is too small
you have specified paperclip to resize your image only if it is larger than the dimensions you have pointed. This is done by the > suffix

And regarding your second part of the question:

You have to do it yourself - check how the paperclip processors work

here is what is written in paperclip documentation [1]

Paperclip supports an extensible selection of post-processors. When you define a set of styles for an attachment, by default it is expected that those "styles" are actually "thumbnails". However, you can do much more than just thumbnail images. **By defining a subclass of Paperclip::Processor, you can perform any processing you want on the files that are attached**. Any file in your Rails app's lib/paperclip_processors directory is automatically loaded by paperclip, allowing you to easily define custom processors. You can specify a processor with the :processors option to has_attached_file:

has_attached_file :scan, :styles => { :text => { :quality => :better } },
                          :processors => [:ocr]

This would load the hypothetical class Paperclip::Ocr, which would have the hash "{ :quality => :better }" passed to it along with the uploaded file. For more information about defining processors, see Paperclip::Proc

[1] https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip